# How to connect iphone/ipad with a remote MSSQLSERVER database?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sql-server-2008

Does somebody has an idea?? I've been googling it but didnt found so much :/

Comment: I pasted the title of this question in to Google, accepted the correction it offered (space in MSQL SERVER) and the first four links were all relevant.  This was the best one: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3942-retrieve-information-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a web service and call it from your Ipad/Iphone client.

The web service would be in charge of getting and setting data on the database.

Comment: thank you but that is what i was trying to avoid XD but yeap there isn't another solution XD